# Python not showing the [matplotlib] window with openCV results

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, syntax-error

I'm working on OpenCV 2.4.9 . Below is my code -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from   matplotlib import pyplot as plt

BLUE = [255,0,0]

img1 = cv2.imread( 'sachin.png' )

replicate  = cv2.copyMakeBorder( img1, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE )
reflect    = cv2.copyMakeBorder( img1, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT )
reflect101 = cv2.copyMakeBorder( img1, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101 )
wrap       = cv2.copyMakeBorder( img1, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_WRAP )
constant   = cv2.copyMakeBorder( img1, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = BLUE )

plt.subplot(231), plt.imshow( img1,       'gray' ), plt.title( 'ORIGINAL' )
plt.subplot(232), plt.imshow( replicate,  'gray' ), plt.title( 'REPLICATE')
plt.subplot(233), plt.imshow( reflect,    'gray' ), plt.title( 'REFLECT' )
plt.subplot(234), plt.imshow( reflect101, 'gray' ), plt.title( 'REFLECT_101' )
plt.subplot(235), plt.imshow( wrap,       'gray' ), plt.title( 'WRAP' )
plt.subplot(236), plt.imshow( constant,   'gray' ), plt.title( 'CONSTANT' )

plt.show()
```

When I run the above code I got the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "border.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

After googling, I found that Matplotlib module was missing then I installed it from the following commands - 
**sudo python get-pip.py** to install **pip**. **sudo python get-pip.py** to install **matplotlib**.
After when I run the code no error was reported and the code ran successfully but no windows are displayed. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Check your components ( ref. **`Step 0`** & **`1`** in answer below ) and syntax ( ref. a non-PEP8 re-formatted source-code above  - **`a = 2, b = 3, GUI_openCV()`** and compare with **`a = 2; b = 3; GUI_openCV()`**)

Answer (score 1):

### Step 0: test if `openCV` part is fully working

This shall provide you a reasonable feeling the `CV2` works independently of `matplotlib` well

Try a simple scenario like this. It opens a new **`cv2`**-window **silently** which need not get O/S-focus, so find it in your TaskBar and pick it manually.

This simple **`GUI_openCV()`** test shall proof your `cv2` installation is working :

```
import numpy
import cv2

def nothing_asCallback( x ):
    pass

def GUI_openCV():
    # Create a black image, a window
   img = numpy.zeros( ( 300, 512, 3 ), numpy.uint8 )

   cv2.namedWindow( 'cv2-image' )
# ----------------------------------------------------------------GUI-<state>
   s = 1
   r = 0
   g = 0
   b = 0
   # -------------------------------------------------------------GUI-<ACTOR>-s
   # create trackbars for color change
   cv2.createTrackbar( 'R',        'cv2-image', 0, 255, nothing_asCallback )
   cv2.createTrackbar( 'G',        'cv2-image', 0, 255, nothing_asCallback )
   cv2.createTrackbar( 'B',        'cv2-image', 0, 255, nothing_asCallback )
   # create switch for ON/OFF functionality
   switch = '0 : OFF \n1 : ON'
   cv2.createTrackbar( switch,     'cv2-image', 0,   1, nothing_asCallback )
   # --------------------------------------------------------------------
   print " ------------------------------------------------- press [ESC] to exit "
   while( 1 ):                                                # GUI-mainloop()
       cv2.imshow( 'cv2-image', img )
    
       k = cv2.waitKey( 1 ) & 0xFF
    
       if k == 27:
           break
    
       # get current positions of four trackbars ----------- # GUI-<vars>-DETECT >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> can be done "internally" ...cv2.createTrackbar( 'R', 'windowName', aGuiStateVariable_R, 255, nothing_asCallback )
       new_r = cv2.getTrackbarPos( 'R',    'cv2-image' )
       new_g = cv2.getTrackbarPos( 'G',    'cv2-image' )
       new_b = cv2.getTrackbarPos( 'B',    'cv2-image' )
       new_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos( switch, 'cv2-image' )
    
       if ( new_s != s or new_r != r or new_g != g or new_b != b ):
           #------------------------------------------------ # DUMB-<state>-UPDATE
           s = new_s
           r = new_r
           g = new_g
           b = new_b
           #------- ---------------------------------------- # DUMB-ACTOR 
           if s == 0:
               img[:] = 0
           else:
               img[:] = [b,g,r]
           pass
       else:
           pass
   pass
   # -----------------------------------------------------------------
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### Step 1: test if `matplotlib` ad-hoc installation works

Next comes your ad-hoc **`matplotlib`** installation.

Use whatever, trivial in construction, to validate the **`matplotlib`** part:

```
"""
Simple demo of the fill function.
"""
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = numpy.linspace( 0, 1 )
y = numpy.sin( 4 * numpy.pi * x ) * numpy.exp( -5 * x )

plt.fill( x, y, 'b' )
plt.grid( True )
plt.show()
```

Or run any matplotlib demo from documentation to see, if your module was installed correctly.

### Step 2: test `openCV` / `matplotlib` post-processing integration

For successful integration, follow the documentation about different RGB(A)-slicing indices in each part of your code. This and colourmap-datatype mis-alignments account for the most troubles on prototyping.

Do not hesitate to use as many **`cv2.imshow( CV2WINDOW, interimPhaseDATA )`** as comfortable during your ComputeVision projects.

Do not hesitate to split your code into smallest possible `{syntax|processing}-bug-tracking` sprints, which you step-after-step cross-validate in both **`openCV`** and **`matplotlib`** visualisations ( `cv2.imshow()` and `plt.show()` )

This is a common bug-hunting practice called "isolation".

Comment: Step 0 is not working. I mean, no window is displayed. The file gets executed within a millisecond.Step 1 is working fine and I get the expected window showing the result.

Comment: I think your above code to test OpenCV (Step 0) is wrong as you have not defined the function call to GUI_openCV()

Comment: Negative, Pavan, this is not an error, that is an intention. On fast prototyping and the more on bug-fixing, one may freely copy / paste snippets in **`python >>>`** prompt in terminal and test + inspect as needed all the (sub-)components and / or run the **`def`**-ed  functions. **Typically** type `cv2.__version__` before **`GUI_openCV()`** if you are ready to test **`cv2`** part, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put plt.figure() before you generate all your plots.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar error in some previous program using matplotlib. Installing python-tk package resolved it for me.

```
      sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Hope this works!